# How to express inclusive and exclusive relations in relational algebra and relational calculus?

Tags: relational-theory, relational-algebra, relational-calculus

Let be the following simplified database sketch:

- `R1(P,S),R2(S,T) and R3(T,S) with P= people S = Sport and T= Sports Center`

How to find in relational algebra and relational calculus which couples such that each one has at least a sport that the other do and and another that the other do not.

I tried:

Π<sub>p1,p2</sub>(σ<sub>s1!=s2, p1!=p2</sub>(R1))<sub>P→P1,P→P2, S→S1, S→S2</sub>

But I know this is wrong, It doesn't express the second condition at least and I'm not sure on how to express variables renaming.

**Can you help me express such inclusive and exclusive relations?**